# MVC3 access User Profile data outside of controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In our new very large MVC3 application, we have a security problem to solve.  Our structure is that for each controller, there is one viewModel and one viewModelGenerator class.  The viewModelGenerator class is responsible for building the viewModel from as many data tables as required.

Our issue is that each user is restricted to only seeing the data for their "office".  So we have to pass the users "office" information to each viewModelGenerator.

Is there a way to access the user profile data without having to pass it as a parameter from the controller?  I could pass the value in via the constructor, but we are homing there is a cleaner way of doing it. I've seen posts on SO on how to get the user Identity, but not the full profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Our structure is that for each controller, there is one viewModel

That's a wrong structure. You should have a view model per view and not a view model per controller.

> Is there a way to access the user profile data without having to pass
>   it as a parameter from the controller?

No and it is not recommended to have a service layer which pulls such data. This data has to be pushed to the service layer from its owner (which is the UI layer)

This being said in ASP.NET MVC there are more MVCish ways to achieve user authorization. One example is to write a custom `[Authorize]` attribute which will be executed before each action and would verify if the user is authorized to access the information.

Comment: You are correct on structure.  That is not exactly what we are doing, but I simplified the structure to pose the question here.  I took your idea about a custom attribute and came up with a clean way to push the data to the viewModelGenerator through the controller using an interface and a base class.  Thanks for idea

Answer (score 0):

My only thought is to create a shared parent ViewModel which includes the UserProfile as a common field.

So, create a BaseViewModel and set each ViewModel to inherit from BaseViewModel. The only change in ViewModelGenerator should be that you need to set the appropriate values for your UserProfile in the constructor.

I'm using public here for easability, but if it's a security concern would likely use at least protected getters and setters. Something akin to:

```
public class ViewModel1 : BaseViewModel {   
    public ViewModel1 ()
      :base(UserProfile profiledata){
           //Constructor code for ViewModel1   
    } 
}
```

and in BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel{
   public UserProfile profile;    
   public BaseViewModel(UserProfile prof){
      profile = prof;
   }
}
```

Comment: Security at this level is not a concern.  What I'm looking for is a way to pass in the profile without having to use a constructor call from the controller.  If possible.